# Google Play Services have stopped message is popping up continuously on screen

Tags: google-play-store, google-play-services, xiaomi-mi4

Phone is MI4I , Google play services have stopped msg is popping up continuously on screen. None of the conventional methods are working I.e clearing Google play cache is disabled, restore to factory version or uninstall updates or clear data is disabled. Stopped and cleared cache of framework, still issue exists. Any other solution possible?

Can't access play store since it needs this. Thinking of downloading Google Play Services latest version from web and installing. Is it a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried rebooting your phone or deleting some data/apps, because if you don't have much space the app will always crash also you could try to reset the play services to the factory version and try starting Google Play to automatically download the newest version that hopefully works.